# Анимированная кнопка

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Верстаю анимированную кнопку с волнами вокруг. Немогу добиться нужного результата. Пример кода: https://jsfiddle.net/po5cr6je/

Сама кнопка такая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.promo__play {
  background-image: url('https://s32.postimg.org/sxifa8h79/main_bg.jpg');
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.promo__play__content {
  display: table-row;
}

.promo__play__content__item {
  height: 350px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.promo__play__text {
  color: #0e91a0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.promo__play__circle {
  padding-top: 45px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

.circle:after, .circle:before, .promo__play__circle:after, .promo__play__circle:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.promo__play__circle:after, .promo__play__circle:before {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #7796a9;
}

.promo__play__circle:before {
  -webkit-animation: rippl 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rippl 2s linear infinite;
}

.promo__play__circle:after {
  -webkit-animation: rippl 2s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: rippl 2s linear 1s infinite;
}

.circle:after, .circle:before {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #7796a9;
}

.circle:before {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 2s linear infinite;
  animation: ripple 2s linear infinite;
}

.circle:after {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 2s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: ripple 2s linear 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rippl {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.2);
    transform: scale(2.2);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.8);
    transform: scale(2.8);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
    transform: scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rippl {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.2);
    transform: scale(2.2);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.8);
    transform: scale(2.8);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
    transform: scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как из этой баганной кнопки сделать красивую анимацию?)

Comment: так итак анимация уже есть.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Если обратить внимание то анимация очень плохая:( немогу сделать чтобы четко происходило, отступы рандомные

Comment: что значит плохая? четко происходило что?

Comment: Посмотрите http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/d4LVA/1/ может пригодится.

Comment: @YuraIvanov То что нужно) постите как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализация на js+transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/d4LVA/1/

```js
function go() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".anim").addClass('hover');
    var d = $("<div class='anim'/>");
    d.appendTo($(document.body));
    setTimeout(function() {
      d.remove();
    }, 10000);
  }, 1000);
}
go();
```

```css
.apple {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.anim {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 5s linear;
}
.anim.hover {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple"></div>
```